# How to use powerline fonts in wintab

Tags: vimrc

I cannot for the love of me figure out the configuration needed to use [wintabs powerline](https://github.com/zefei/vim-wintabs-powerline) in [vim wintabs](https://github.com/zefei/vim-wintabs). Please help me. I want to make my vim look beautiful.

Comment: What have you tried? How is it working differently from what you expected? Do you have powerline itself set up properly? You should configure that first before adding wintabs... Post the relevant parts of your vimrc too.

Comment: @filbranden Oh i need to have the original powerline installed in order to use wintabs powerline?

Comment: Yes. Wintabs powerline is simply to make powerline work *with* wintabs... If you don't have powerline (or if you don't have wintabs), you won't need it.